# I need help creating a custom counter for items in my SQLite database

Tags: django

I am new to Python and Django and I am trying to count the number items(documents) in my SQLite database base on the status of the document, (canceled or not canceled). I have tried multiple ways to do this but, I cannot find one that works correctly for me. I have tried forloop.counter, .count(), and a few other ways that i found online. All I want to do is go through the database and have it tell me how many canceled procedures I have in the database. I am trying to display the results on a html page. Thanks.

models.py

```
class posts(models.Model):
    OPMnumber = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    title = models.TextField()
    contacts = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    dateLastReviewed = models.DateTimeField()
    reviewDue = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    assignedTo = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    comments = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
def opmStatistics(request):
    """
    Return opmStatus page
    """
    entries = posts.objects.all()#[:10] limits the number of entries 
    displayed
    #opm_count = posts.objects.filter(posts.status=='Canceled').count()

    #return render_to_response('opmStatistics.html', {'posts' : 
    opm_count})
    return render_to_response('opmStatistics.html', {'posts' : entries})
```

My html code:

```
   <tr><td>Current Number of Active Accelerator Operations OPMs: </td>
   <td>
   {% for post in posts %}
   {% if post.status != "Canceled" %}
     {% with OPM_count=forloop.counter %} <!-- how to save final number 
    as variable. -->
        {{OPM_count}} 
      {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}

   </td>
   </tr>
   <br><br>
   <tr><td>Current Number of Canceled Accelerator Operations OPMs: </td>
   <td>
         {% for post in posts %}
         {% if post.status == "Canceled" %}
         {% with OPM_count=forloop.counter %} <!-- how to save final 
         number as variable. this one does not reset to 1, starts where 
         it left off. -->
         {{OPM_count}}
         {% endwith %}
         {% endif %}

         {% endfor %}
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: This isn't clear. You shouldn't be trying to do the actual counting in the database. But what, *exactly*, are you trying to count? What exactly should the output look like?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of procedures that have 'Canceled' in the status field in my database. All i want to do is display that number on my webpage.  The output should be similar to this: Current Number of Canceled Accelerator Operations OPMs: (display number of canceled procedures).

Comment: So you just want a single line? You don't actually want to iterate at all?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is display the total number of procedures that are canceled based on their status field in the database. Count the number of canceled procedures in the database and display the total number on my webpage/template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count a single value, then you should do that in the view. This is not at all something you should be attempting to do in the template.

You were almost there with your original attempt. It should be:

```
def opmStatistics(request):
    """
    Return opmStatus page
    """
    opm_count = posts.objects.filter(status='Canceled').count()

    return render(request, 'opmStatistics.html', {'count': opm_count})
```

and then the template is just:

```
<tr>
 <td>Current Number of Active Accelerator Operations OPMs: </td>
 <td>{{ count }}</td>
</tr>
```